# Alternatives for high-carb foods

Tags: weight-loss, diet, carbohydrate

At work my lunch usually consists of chicken/fish (mackerel/tuna) and a filler in the form of pasta/brown rice. I want to start cutting out more carbs out of my diet as my dinners in most cases consists of carbs in the form of potatoes and vegetables. I am currently on a training schedule to lose body fat while gaining muscle. Is there a healthy low-carb alternative to the traditional pasta and rice that you can recommend that is preferably common in supermarkets and not too expensive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best alternatives to traditional carbs (rice, pasta, bread) is quinoa and beans, which is what I call "the completely balanced foods", because it possess a good amount of carbohydrates, proteins variety of nutrients which makes it a great food if you want to slowly wean out how much carbs you are eating.\

Any time I want to cut a little bit more I eat more beans and quinoa instead of heavy starchy carbs such as rice, pasta, bread.

Comment: Ah yes, beans and quinoa. I have heard many good things. Would there be any down side to me having quinoa every lunch or should I mix it up daily?

Comment: Absolutely no downsides to eating quinoa every day as a substitute.

Comment: @ghost_zfh: I wouldn't say that there're 'no downsides' to eating quinoa everyday. It only has certain nutrients and he'll miss out on other ones if he eats the same thing all the time. With that said, if he mixes up his other meals it shouldn't be that much of a problem as he'll get his nutrients with those that way. So yeah, I kinda agree with you, but felt like I should add that.